# PCR tests entering Antigua from Montserrat

Tags: covid-19, montserrat

I'm hopefully travelling from the UK to Montserrat later this month.  This journey requires passing through Antigua in both directions.  I know I need to do a PCR test in the [five days prior to entering Montserrat](https://www.gov.ms/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Montserrat-Travel-Protocols-Updated-October-1-2021-1.pdf) and in the [four days prior to entering Antigua](https://visitantiguabarbuda.com/travel-advisory/).  On the way out this is no problem as I can take a test at home and be good for entering both Antigua and Montserrat.  On the way back this is problematic.  I cannot find anywhere in Montserrat offering PCR tests, and given the tiny population of the island perhaps there isn't anywhere.  I'm wondering whether there might be an exemption for arrivals to Antigua from Montserrat – that would make sense as the only way in and out of Montserrat is via Antigua, so it's entirely possible it's regarded as part of Antigua for Covid purposes, but I can't see it stated anywhere.  Does anyone know the situation?  The tourism offices in both countries have not yet responded to my queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first google result for *montserrat covid test* is the Montserrat government's [covid-19 page](https://www.gov.ms/covid-19/), which advises that covid testing is available on Mondays and Wednesdays between 1:00 and 3:00pm at the St John's Health Centre. Results normally take two days to be delivered, but apparently can be expedited to be delivered the next day if necessary. There is also a phone number to call to discuss if other arrangements are possible in case the testing schedule listed there is completely incompatible with your flight schedule.

All of this is, of course, subject to change and should be reconfirmed when you travel.

Comment: It may be the first result when you search, but it's not when I do.  Google modifies its results based on the country you're searching from, your search history, and various other undocumented factors.  But thank you for the answer which is helpful.